# Updating a Geographical Visualization in Bokeh on button click event

Tags: python, event-handling, visualization, geocoding, bokeh

I am very new to the Bokeh visualization library in Python. I have built a geographical map visualization using Bokeh and Google Maps API that allows me to see the distribution of my data for a particular location (city) in the US. I have further factorised that data by gender (using a distinct color for each gender in my dataset, male, female and unknown). What I am aiming to do now is, to render this visualization on a button click event. After going through various documentation in Bokeh, research on stack overflow and other similar sites, I have come up with the following code so far,

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import *
from bokeh.plotting import gmap
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, curdoc
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.events import ButtonClick
from bokeh.models import Button
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.events import ButtonClick

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc

output_file("gmap.html")

#parameters
server = 'x.x.x.x\abc'
db = 'abc'

# Create the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.686293, lng=-97.3614409, map_type="roadmap", zoom=13)
p = gmap("My_Google_Maps_API_Key", map_options, title="Client_Distribution", plot_width=1000, plot_height=600)


def callback(event):
    print ('abc')
    global p, map_options
    sql = """
        with CTE AS
            (SELECT
            CR.ClientID, CR.Latitude, CR.Longtitude
            FROM 
            Company C LEFT JOIN ClientRegistration CR on C.CompanyID = CR.CompanyID
            WHERE
            C.CompanyID = xxx AND (CR.Latitude IS NOT NULL AND CR.Longtitude IS NOT NULL)
            )
        SELECT
        C.ClientID, C.Latitude, C.Longtitude, CL.Sex
        FROM
        CTE C LEFT JOIN Clients CL on C.ClientID = CL.ClientID
    """
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)

    print (df)

    df[['Latitude','Longtitude']] = df[['Latitude','Longtitude']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].astype('str')

    map_options = GMapOptions(lat=37.686293, lng=-97.3614409, map_type="roadmap", zoom=13)
    p = gmap("My_Google_Maps_API_Key", map_options, title="Client_Distribution", plot_width = 1000, plot_height = 600)

    lat = df['Latitude'].tolist()
    lon = df['Longtitude'].tolist()
    sex = df['Sex'].tolist()

    source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(latitude = lat,
              longitude = lon,
              gender = sex
               )
    )

    print (source)
    color_mapper = CategoricalColorMapper(factors=['M', 'F', 'U'], palette=['Red', 'Blue', 'Green'])

    print("reached end")

    p.circle(x="longitude", y="latitude", size=4, fill_alpha=0.9, source=source,
             fill_color={'field': 'gender', 'transform': color_mapper},
             line_color={'field': 'gender', 'transform': color_mapper})

    x = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    p.circle(x, y, legend="Male", color="red")
    p.circle(x, 2 * y, legend="Female", color="Blue")
    p.circle(x, 3 * y, legend="Unknown", color="Green")

    curdoc().clear()
    curdoc().add_root(column(p))


    print("reached the very end")



# add a button widget and configure with the call back
button = Button(label="Gender")
button.on_event(ButtonClick, callback)

# put the button and plot in a layout and add to the document

curdoc().add_root(column(button, p))
```

I can get the underlying google map visualization and the button to display, but I am not able to display the factorisation of clients by gender and the labelling of these data points on a button click. When I click the button nothing happens to my map. Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The use-case that was originally envisioned for Bokeh, and the one that is most well-exercised and proven, is to create plots up front, then *update them*. This is pretty much how ever example in the published docs and examples does things. Replacing plots wholesale, as you are doing above, is definitely currently a "YMMV" type operation. I'd suggest re-working your example to be more like the examples and docs, i.e. create your plot and glyphs once up front, and then update only the data sources in callbacks (this will also be more efficient to boot)

Comment: Thanks bigreddot, I will try to modify my example as per your suggestion.